# Temporizador, problemas con el decremento de minutos y horas

Tags: c

necesito una pequeña ayuda, resulta que necesito crear un temporizador en lenguaje c, los segundo se me decrementan normal, pero al momento de llegar a los minutos, estos no decrementan, si no que el programa finaliza, lo hago con `for` anidados, otra cosa, no se bien que tipo de función utilizar para que después que los segundos se decrementen, estos comiencen devuelta a decrementarse pero esta vez desde 59, no desde el numero que el usuario ingreso, pondre lo que tengo de codigo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int hr,min,seg;
    int hra,min2,seg4;
    printf("\t Temporizador. \t");
    printf("\n Por favor ingrese las horas \n");
    printf("\n ==> ");
    scanf("%d",&hr);
    printf("\n Por favor ingrese los minutos \n");
    printf("\n ==> ");
    scanf("%d",&min);
    printf("\n Por favor ingrese los segundos \n");
    printf ("\n ==> ");
    scanf("%d",&seg);
    
    for (hra=0;hra<=hr;hr--)
    {
        for (min2=0;min2<=min;min--)
        {
            for (seg4=1;seg4<=seg;seg--)
            {
                system ("cls");
                printf ("%d:%d:%d",hr,min,seg);
                Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Se supone que al ser ciclos anidados, se me tiene que cumplir el ultimo `for` para que siga el siguiente y luego el principal, de abajo hacia arriba.

Trate de seguir la lógica de un cronometro que anteriormente hice, lo adjunto a continuación.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    
//  Cronómetro
    int min,seg;
    for(min=0; min<=2; min++)//Este ciclo controla los minutos
    {
        for(seg=1;seg<=6;seg++)//Este controla los segundos
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("%d:%d",min,seg);
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Cualquier tipo de ayuda es muy bienvenida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código no tiene ni pies ni cabeza, si introduces `1` como horas, `1` como minutos y `1` como segundos el total de espera será de tres segundos no de tres mil seis cientos uno.

Yo simplificaría todo el código para contar segundos y haría un solo bucle, además de usar variables con nombres menos confusos y hacer menos llamadas redundantes a `printf`:

```
int horas,minutos,segundos,total;

printf("\t Temporizador. \t"
       "\n Por favor ingrese las horas \n"
       "\n ==> ");
scanf("%d",&horas);

printf("\n Por favor ingrese los minutos \n"
       "\n ==> ");
scanf("%d",&minutos);

printf("\n Por favor ingrese los segundos \n"
       "\n ==> ");
scanf("%d",&segundos);

total = (horas * 3600) + (minutos * 60) + segundos;

while (total--)
{
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", total / 3600, (total % 3600) / 60, total % 60);
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Haces un uso raro de los `for` y los índices para hacer los recorridos. Siguiendo tu código tal cual, para que continúe el decremento tienes que volver a inicializar las variables segundos y minutos a `59` cuando termina cada bucle. Algo como esto:

```
    for (hra = 0; hra <= hr; hr--)
    {
        for (min2 = 0; min2 <= min; min--)
        {
            for (seg4 = 0; seg4 <= seg; seg--)
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", hr, min, seg);
                Sleep(1000);
            }
            seg = 59;
        }
        min = 59;
    }
```

También he modificado el `printf` con el que muestras la hora, para que incluya los ceros a la izquierda y parezca más un reloj. Y mucho ojo porque el bucle de los segundos debe empezar en `0` y no en `1`.

Pero por mi parte, utilizaría los bucles con decremento. Me parece más sencillo de seguir y más intuitivo. Sería algo como esto:

```
    for (hra = hr; hra >= 0; --hra) {
        for( min2 = min; min2 >= 0; --min2) {
            for (seg4 = seg; seg4 >= 0; --seg4) {
                system("cls");
                printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", hra, min2, seg4);
                Sleep(1000);
            }
            seg = 59;
        }
        min = 59;

    }
```

Cada bucle empieza con el valor introducido y se va decrementando hasta cero. Cuando llega a `0`, se inicializa de nuevo a `59` para volver a empezar. Hasta que todo llega a `0`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo.